# Apply style to body to match selection on Word document renders unknown results

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2007, styles

While formatting a Word document, I applied the action, "Apply style to body to match selection".

The document ended up looking very wrong with the formatting all over the place - it even affected  the numbers inside tables.

I'm not sure what happened or how to correct this.

Comment: I Wonder Why CTRL+Z is not nowrking!

Comment: No . Undo is not working

Comment: @Lijo, you can associate your Super User and Stack Overflow accounts by clicking on your name at the top of the page and using the *Accounts* tab.

Comment: Ctrl-Z is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You've changed the styles in your document, but you can always modify them back:

1. Either change the affected styles if you know which they are, as explained in [Modify a style](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP051895621033.aspx).
2. Or, as you say you have backup documents, copy the affected styles from the backup, as explained in [Using the Organizer to Manage Styles](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T001351_Using_the_Organizer_to_Manage_Styles.html).